Can not prevent static loading of data while building from Vercel
Currently developing a very basic web app. The whole idea is that anyone that accesses the page through the URL, puts a text on a textbox, clicks OK and the message is displayed. This text is recorded on a MongoDB collection and pulled from there.
I am using NextJS 14.2 with App directory and directly building from Git on Vercel. My current problem is that on each new build taken on Vercel, current value of the message is recorded, statically. When a new value is entered and recorded on the database (this was checked) webpage is not updated as it is statically generated on new commit.
I moved my page to use server components, added headers for no cache on all API code.
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic';
export const revalidate = 0; 

x-vercel-cache value is MISS, set cache's to 0 of max age. I believe there is still something I need to set on the Vercel side but I am out of options.
Edit: I confirmed that when the cache is deleted manually on Vercel, new data appears but this does not solve the problem.
